# How to find a string within a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, string-matching

I have the list with like 100,000 site link strings

- Each link is unique, but it has consistent `?Item=`
- Then, it's either nothing or it continues after `&` symbol.

My question is: How do I pull out the item numbers?

I know replace function can offer similar functionality, but it works with Fixed sizes, in my case string can be different in size.

Link example:
`www.site.com?sadfsf?sdfsdf&adfasfd?Item=JGFGGG55555`
or
`www.site.com?sadfsf?sdfsdf&adfasfd?Item=JGFGGG55555&sdafsdfsdfsdf`

In both cases I need to get `JGFGGG55555` only

Comment: Not sure I understand but `instr` could help you find a string within a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this always is the last portion of the string, you can use the following:

```
=MID(A1, FIND("?Item=", A1) + 6, 99)
```

This assumes:

- no item numbers will be over 99 digits.
- no additional fields follow the item number.

**Edit:**

With the update to your question, it is apparent you have some strings with additional data after the `?Item=` field. Without using VBA there is not a simple means of using `MID` and `FIND` to extract this.

However you could create a column which acts as a placeholder.

For example, create a column using:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("?Item=",A1)+6,99)
```

This gets you the following value: `JGFGGG55555&sdafsdfsdfsdf`

Next, create a column using:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("&",B2)),B2,LEFT(B2,FIND("&",B2)-1))
```

This produces: `JGFGGG55555` by searching the first value for a `&` and using the portion before it. If it is not found, the first value is simply repeated.

Answer (score 0):

This formula should work for both the examples given:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("=",A1),IFERROR(LEN(A1)-FIND("&",A1,FIND("=",A1))-1,LEN(A1)+1-FIND("=",A1)))
```